# How to group two different arrays by one common variable?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have two different arrays. one will be for the title of the national park and other data I can use from that, and the other is alerts from the whole NPS system. I have compared the two arrays and the one distinct thing they have in common is **parkCode**. How can I go about grouping them by national park...example being:

1. Yellowstone National Park
   -alert from yellowstone
2. Arches National Park 
   -alert from arches

here is the data I am working with..

National Park Names:

```
 0:
 description: "."
 designation: "National Park"
 directionsInfo: "From Boston take I-95 north to Augusta, Maine, then 
 Route 3 east to Ellsworth, and on to Mount Desert Island. For an 
 alternate route, continue on I-95 north to Bangor, Maine, then take 
 Route 1A east to Ellsworth. In Ellsworth, take Route 3 to Mount Desert 
 Island."
 directionsUrl: "http://www.nps.gov/acad/planyourvisit/directions.htm"
 fullName: "Acadia National Park"
 id: "6DA17C86-088E-4B4D-B862-7C1BD5CF236B"
 latLong: "lat:44.30777545, long:-68.30063316"
 name: "Acadia"
 **parkCode: "acad"**
 states: "ME"
 url: "https://www.nps.gov/acad/index.htm"
```

Example Alert:

```
113:
category: "Park Closure"
description: "The Elwha area is closed indefinitely to vehicle traffic 
beyond Madison Falls parking lot due to extensive flood damage to the 
Olympic Hot Springs Road. There is limited parking and turnaround space 
at the Madison Falls parking area."
id: "84646EA9-1DD8-B71B-0BD7AECDC56BD8AE"
**parkCode: "acad"**
title: "Elwha (Olympic Hot Springs) Road Closed to Vehicle Access"
url: "https://www.nps.gov/olym/planyourvisit/current-road-conditions.htm"
```

Comment: Please post a real data structure and not the output of (presumably) `console.log`. Is it JSON or an array?

Comment: Along with workable data also provide sample of expected results

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your alerts as JavaScript objects in an array called `alerts`, you can "group" them by park in an object like this:

```
const alertsByPark = {};
alerts.forEach(alert => {
  // If there are no alerts recorded for the park yet, add the park as a key to the alertsByPark object
  if (!alertsByPark[alert.parkCode]) alertsByPark[alert.parkCode] = [];
  alertsByPark[alert.parkCode].push(alert);
});
```

this will set `alertsByPark` to a data format that looks like this:

```
{
  acad: [...],
  ...
}
```

with a key for each parkCode and an array of all of the alerts from that park.

To output data in the format you show in your question, where each alert is shown after the formal name of the park referenced in its parkCode\, you can use `find` on the array of parks to get the full park data for the `parkCode` referenced in the alert.

```
alerts.forEach((alert, i) => {
  // Locate the park with the parkCode matching the alert parkCode
  const park = parks.find(({ parkCode }) => parkCode === alert.parkCode);
  console.log(`${i}. ${park.fullName} - ${alert.description}`);
})
```

This again assumes you have your alerts in an array of objects called `alerts` and that you have your parks in an array of objects called `parks`. It will output a list like

```
1. Acadia National Park - The Elwha area is closed indefinitely to...
2. park name - alert description
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

```
parks.map(park => {
 park.alerts = alerts.filter(alert => alert.parkCode === park.parkCode)
 return park
})
```

This returns a parks array with prop 'alerts' (array of alerts)

**Example:**

```
const parks = [
 { name: 'Yellowstone', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { name: 'Arcadia', parkCode: 'ar' },
 { name: 'Arches', parkCode: 'arch' },
 { name: 'A park without alerts', parkCode: 'PARK' }
 ]

const alerts = [
 { description: 'Alert 1', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'Alert 2', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'Alert 3 ', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'Alert 4', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'Alert 5', parkCode: 'arch' },
 { description: 'Alert 6', parkCode: 'ar' },
 { description: 'Alert 7', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'Alert 8', parkCode: 'arch' },
 { description: 'Alert 9', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'Alert 10', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'Alert 11', parkCode: 'ar' },
 { description: 'Alert 12', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'Alert 13', parkCode: 'ar' },
 { description: 'Alert 14', parkCode: 'ar' },
 { description: 'Alert 15', parkCode: 'ys' },
 { description: 'An alert to unknown park', parkCode: 'ALERT' }
 ]

 let parksWithAlerts = parks.map(park => {
   park.alerts = alerts.filter(alert => alert.parkCode === park.parkCode)
   return park
 })

 console.dir(parksWithAlerts[0])
```

---

```
{ name: 'Yellowstone',
  parkCode: 'ys',
  alerts:
   [ { description: 'Alert 1', parkCode: 'ys' },
   { description: 'Alert 2', parkCode: 'ys' },
   { description: 'Alert 3 ', parkCode: 'ys' },
   { description: 'Alert 4', parkCode: 'ys' },
   { description: 'Alert 7', parkCode: 'ys' },
   { description: 'Alert 9', parkCode: 'ys' },
   { description: 'Alert 10', parkCode: 'ys' },
   { description: 'Alert 12', parkCode: 'ys' },
   { description: 'Alert 15', parkCode: 'ys' } ] }
```

**Joined alerts**

```
let parksWithAlerts = parks.map(park => {
   park.alerts = alerts.filter(alert => alert.parkCode === park.parkCode)
   return park
 }).map(park =>{
    park.alerts = park.alerts.map(alert => alert.description).join(' - ')
    return park
 })



console.dir(parksWithAlerts[0])
```

---

```
{ name: 'Yellowstone',
  parkCode: 'ys',
  alerts: 'Alert 1 - Alert 2 - Alert 3  - Alert 4 - Alert 7 - Alert 9 - Alert 10 - Alert 12 - Alert 15' }
```